# silverlight do Not start work stuck on download 100% debug do not start

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Hello I got another programmer's project I can not run the project
 Stuck on 100% can not download the silverlight do not start debuging

Answer (score 0):

The code do not get to fonction MainPage
in MainPage.xmal the code need some paramter query string if it do not get tham the code do not call function MainPage and the silverlight get stack on 100% downlaod